# Iterate over X3DOM nodes in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom-events, x3dom

I'm trying to iterate over X3DOM nodes in D3.js, but I'm getting an error.

Here's the code:

```
  var disktransform = scene.selectAll('.disktransform');
  var shape = disktransform
                  .datum(slices)
                  .selectAll('.shape')
                  .data(partition.nodes)
            .enter()
            .append('shape')
                    .attr('class', 'shape')
                    .attr('data-name', function(d, i) { return d.name + ' ' + i; })

  shape
            .append('appearance')
            .append('material')
                    .attr('diffuseColor', function (d, i) { return color(d.name); })
    ;
  d3.selectAll('shape.shape').each(function (d) { console.log(d); d.node().addEventListener('click', function (event) { alert('key'); alert(d.attr('data-name')); }); });
```

and here's the error.  As you can see, it's trying to use `HTMLUnknownElement.node()`.  How do I get the above code to work with X3DOM?

```
TypeError: d.node is not a function
    at HTMLUnknownElement.<anonymous> (cross_chart.js:136)
    at d3.js:962
    at d3_selection_each (d3.js:968)
    at Array.d3_selectionPrototype.each (d3.js:961)
    at CrossChart.addPath (cross_chart.js:136)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (cross_chart.js:263)
    at d3.js:962
    at d3_selection_each (d3.js:968)
    at Array.d3_selectionPrototype.each (d3.js:961)
    at Array.CrossChart.draw (cross_chart.js:196)
    (anonymous function) @ angular.js:10126
    $get @ angular.js:7398
    $get.Scope.$digest @ angular.js:12669
    $get.Scope.$apply @ angular.js:12915
    done @ angular.js:8450
    completeRequest @ angular.js:8664
    xhr.onreadystatechange @ angular.js:8603
```

Comment: I have also replaced d with this in the each function, but no luck.

Comment: While I don't have access to your code to confirm the issue, I have 2 suggestions:

    - use x3dom.reload() to ensure the DOM is properly up to date
    - use d3.select('x3d').node().runtime.shootRay(x, y) on clicks to identify target objects

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
d3.selectAll('shape.shape').each(function (d) { console.log(d); d3.select(this).node().addEventListener('click', function (event) { alert('key'); alert(d3.select(this).attr('data-name')); }); });
```